# Utimaco HSM cxitool return error "NO_DEVICE_AVAILABLE"

Tags: hardware-security-module

i have error when login using the cxitool.
this the command i used "*cxitool Dev=3005@localhost LogonSign=CRYPTO_USER,CRYPTO_USER.key#123456 ListKeys*"

it return this error
"*HSM::ConnectionException
thrown in login
Error::NO_DEVICE_AVAILABLE*"

There's no error when i used csadm to login.
"*csadm  Dev=3005@localhost LogonSign=CRYPTO_USER,CRYPTO_USER.key#123456 ListUsers*"

[update]
i realize User with CXI_GROUP able to use the cxitool. When i use user USR_0000 i able to use the cxitool without the error NO_DEVICE_AVAILABLE
[image]

Comment: I work for Utimaco.  The answer depends on many things: Version of the PKCS11 provider, platform (host OS, etc), version of the firmware.  1) What is the value of CS_PKCS11_R2_CFG (or R3_CFG if you are using R3).  2) In the file pointed to by the CFG, what is the value of the Device line.  3) You have port 3005, are you running cs_multi 3, etc.  Add that information to your post, and I will explain in an answer what is wrong/how to fix.